# CSS Carousel Navigation Issues

Tags: html, css, django, carousel

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
.col-md-3
{
display: inline-block;
margin-left:-4px;
}

          .carousel-indicators .active {
          background-color: blue;
            }
    
          .col-md-3 img{
    
          width: 227px;
          max-height: 242px;
          }
    
          body .carousel-indicator li{
          background-color: blue;
          }
    
          body .carousel-indicators{
          bottom: 0;
          }
    
          body .carousel-control-prev-icon,
          body .carousel-control-next-icon{
          background-color: blue;
          }
    
          .carousel-control-prev,
          .carousel-control-next{
          **top: auto;
          bottom: auto;**
          }
           body .no-padding{
           padding-left: 0,
           padding-right: 0;
           }

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% load static %}
\<div class="container"\>

    <!--Slideshow starts here -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in allProds %}
    <h5 class="my-4">Flash Sale On {{product.0.category}} - Recommended Items</h5>

\<div id="demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel"\>
\<ul class="carousel-indicators"\>
\<li data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"\>\</li\>

       {% for i in range %}
      <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="{{i}}" ></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    
    
    <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
    
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src='/media/{{product.0.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{product.0.product_name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.0.desc}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    
    
        {% for i in product|slice:"1:"%}
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{i.desc}}</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add To Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
      </div><div class="carousel-item">
        {% endif %}
    
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

\</div\>
\</div\>
\<!-- left and right controls for the slide --\>
\<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="prev"\>
\<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"\>\</span\>
\</a\>
\<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="next"\>
\<span class="carousel-control-next-icon"\>\</span\>
\</a\>
{% endfor %}
\</div\>
{% endblock %}
```

**This is the code of my index.html page**

**I am getting one carousel navigation which can control the 2nd slide but I want two navigation here which can control both slides.**
I inspect my page and set the navigation prev icon's top and bottom to auto but there wasn't any changes.

**I want to solve the navigation problem**
**I want to know about the CSS fault**

Comment: That's not HTML, there's a lot of templating syntax in there. You should really present a proper [mre] of your issue, with a static version of the resulting HTML. Maybe that would already make it a little clearer, what you actually want, because currently, I can't even tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
   
     <div class="carousel-item active">
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
         <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
           <img src='/media/{{product.0.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
           <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">{{product.0.product_name}}</h5>
               <p class="card-text">{{product.0.desc}}</p>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   
   
       {% for i in product|slice:"1:"%} <div class="carousel-item"> #maybe this can solve it
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
         <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
           <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
           <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
             <p class="card-text">{{i.desc}}</p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add To Cart</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
     </div>
       {% endif %}
   
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

Comment: No sir it's not working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).